# Not able to import header file of custom framework in pod

Tags: objective-c, xcode7, cocoapods

I created a pod with custom framework. When I installed pod and tried to use header file from custom framework in the another project, I'm getting file not found error.

PFB the podspec file I created.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
s.name         = 'SamplePod'
s.version      = '0.1'
s.summary      = 'Sample pod using custom framework'
s.homepage     = '/Users/vigneshkarthik_n/Documents/My Workspace/SamplePod'
s.authors      = 'Vigneshkarthik'

s.source       = { :git =>'/Users/vigneshkarthik_n/Documents/PodSpecNew/SamplePod’ }
s.source_files = 'SamplePod/*.{h,m}','Custom.framework/Headers/*.h'
s.framework    = 'UIKit','Foundation'

s.prefix_header_contents = pch_AF
s.vendored_frameworks = 'Custom.framework'
s.preserve_paths   = 'Custom.framework/**/*'
s.resource            = 'Custom.framework'
s.public_header_files ='SamplePod/*.h'

end
```

I'm keeping the source code and podspec file in local git.

Comment: did you try all of these ways :  #import "file.h" and #import <modulename/file.h> or @import moduleName  ??